# How do I fix stutters in Dead Cells?

Tags: technical-issues, pc, dead-cells

Dead Cells is still in Early Access, but I want to play now, and the game stutters, even though I have modern hardware. What can I do to reduce/fix the stuttering?

Comment: I think a good answer here is "it's early access", it's bound to have bugs and instability.

Comment: How substantial are your stutters?  I don't think I've ever had them affect my gameplay.

Comment: The stutters are on the godawful level of substance. I've read on reddit and steam forums very similar descriptions of what was happening on my copmuter, but people there had all kinds of hardware, ranging from budget to the top tier. Eventually these stutters seemed to disappear. Maybe there's some optimization going on which fixes the stutters after a few hours of playing, I'm still not sure. All I know is that they stopped when I disabled the network adapter.

Comment: To clarify, stuttering still happens even after I've played for many hours in total. Having internet enabled is still noticeably worse than when it's disabled.

Answer (score 2):

One unlikely solution to stuttering and freezes is to disable internet connection. I can't explain it, but it worked for me wonders. Go to `Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections` or type `view network connections` into the Start input panel, and disable your internet adapter by right-clicking. After playing, re-enable it to be able to use internet again. For some reason a custom Windows Firewall rule to block the game exe didn't work for me. Obviously, this solution might not be needed in the future, as the developers are still working on the game, but for now that's what works.

Answer (score 1):

The major thing that fixed it for me was just putting it into Windowed Mode. I was able to run the game flawlessly on my comically weak Surface Pro 4 with an M3 processor by just switching out of Full Screen mode.

They also fixed some of the lag when they recently released the full game, so this isn't as much of a problem now anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest updating drivers for your gfx card. If you are using Radeon Crimson drivers then go to the game options menu, hit "Dead Cells", and disable morphologic filtering, enamble vsync and 3 buffering in OpenGL, and decrease tesselation to levels like x4.